# Method orderBy does not exist in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a piece of code like this:

```
$products = Product::all()

if ($search_value) {
    $products = $products->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search_value%");
}

$products = $products->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(10)->take(10)->with('tags')->get();
```

I got the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method orderBy does not exist.
```

I guess `orderBy` need to follow `Product::` directly, but I can't save `$products = Product::`, can I?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're trying to use `orderBy()` method on Eloquent collection. Try to use [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortbydesc) instead.

Alternatively, you could change `$products = Product::all();` to `$products = new Product();`. Then all your code will work as you expect.

Comment: Is it possible to assign an `Eloquent model` (i.e. `Product`) to `$products`, rather than get a collection which contains all reocrds?

Comment: Sure. You can change `$products = Product::all();` to `$products = new Product();`

Answer (score 24):

just use the one line code it will work fine

```
$product= Product::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

use [sortByDesc('id')](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortbydesc) or simple [sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby) inside use the variable through which you wanna sort like i add id

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the list of all data and grab it in descending order try this:

```
$post = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are first getting `all()` data and then trying to sort which is wrong. You have to fix this by removing

```
$products = Product::all()
```

and changing your code into something like this

```
if ($search_value) {
    $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search_value%");
}
else {
    $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(10)->take(10)->with('tags')->get();
}
```

Hope you get idea to tweak your code.

Comment: It's my current work around....but I try to avoid doing the `orderBy`, `skip`, etc twice

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

remove all from `$products = Product::all()` and then put `get()` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table_Data = DB::table('tbl_product')->orderBy('id','DESC');
```

You can use this...

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on laravel collections and fetching records with Query so we have various ways to fetch the data.

- Directly fetching from model like mentioned above in the answers i.e. `Product::orderBy('created_at')->get() or DB::table('products')->orderBy('created_at')->get();`.
- Another way to solve this is when using relations like fetching data through relations on model i.e. if Product models contains `hadMany` to `orders` and we want to get ordered records from it then we can do in one way:

`$product = Product::first(); $product->orders;`

// Now you can not
use operations on this so you can do something
like:

`$product->orders()->orderBy('created_at')->first();  //This will give the latest record.`

Let me know if need clarifications regarding this.
there are also a lot of ways but need to have clear idea about Laravel collections. One is `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and another is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. They have some common methods but not all.