# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderby does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller, custom-authentication

```
 $posts = Post::all()->orderby('created_at','desc')->where('usr_id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->get();

    return view('admin.profile',compact('userInfo' , 'posts'));
```

i am making a custom auth for a journal activity but i cant sort the content i shows this error

"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderby does not exist. "

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be because you typed `orderby` instead of `orderBy` (notice the uppercase). See [laravel orderBy documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#orderby) if needed.

Plus, as mentionned by other, don't use `all()` if you need to do other thing (where clause, order by, etc) in you query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = Post::where('usr_id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->orderby('created_at','desc')->get();
```

True query like that. When you take all() already query done.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$posts = Post::where('usr_id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->orderby('created_at','desc')->get();
```

you cant use `all()` and orderBy because `all()` does not allow the modification of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Change the orderby to orderBy. This could be the reason you are getting the error.

```
$posts = Post::all()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('usr_id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->get();

return view('admin.profile',compact('userInfo' , 'posts'));
```

Or...

If you want to get specific number of posts you can do it this way to avoid using the `Post::all`

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('usr_id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->paginate(5);

return view('admin.profile',compact('userInfo' , 'posts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is pretty confusing and just got me as well.

The actual problem isn't the capitilization typo (`orderby` versus `orderBy`) but rather the fact that you're using `->all()` instead of just `Model::orderBy()->...`

The moment you use `->all()` the object is transformed to another type of collection object and the normal methods one would expect do not exist.

In this case you should rather use `sortBy()`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760963/method-orderby-does-not-exist-in-laravel-eloquent).